# В чём отличие выражений "про меня" и "обо мне"?

Tags: выбор-слов, фразеология

Эти выражения очень похожи.

"Про" и "обо" — это слова с почти что одинаковым значением, "меня" или "мне" зависит только от слов, стоящих перед ними. И мне стало интересно, в чем же разница и есть ли она вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлогом **про** в таком контексте намекают на *конкретную* информацию о человеке, обычно известную собеседнику и связанную, например, с *действиями* того человека или с *ситуацией*, в которой он оказался. При этом адресат информации может близко знать человека, о котором идёт речь. Предлог **о(бо)** в этом отношении *нейтрален*: подразумеваемая информация может оказаться самой *общей*.

> Она рассказала **про** меня маме [что её сын вчера курил].
>
> Она рассказала **обо** мне родителям [какой интересный у неё бойфренд].

Answer (score 3):

Справочник по правописанию и стилистике Д. Э. Розенталя. § 199. Выбор предлога

Синонимический ряд образуют предлоги с изъяснительным значением, например:

*разговоры о поездке — про поездку — насчет поездки — относительно поездки — касательно поездки*

В этих сочетаниях можно отметить УБЫВАЮЩУЮ КОНКРЕТИЗАЦИЮ предмета речи и СТИЛИСТИЧЕСКОЕ различие: РАЗГОВОРНЫЙ характер предлогов ***про*** и ***насчет***, КНИЖНЫЙ (присущий деловой речи) — предлогов ***касательно*** и ***относительно*** и НЕЙТРАЛЬНЫЙ характер предлога ***о*** при глаголах речи или мысли и соответствующих существительных.